# Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson target framework not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, command-line-interface, .net-5

I have two different computers with the .NET SDK 5.0.202 installed. One is running Windows 10 and the other Windows Server 2016.

On Windows 10, I run `dotnet build` on a .NET 5 project, and it compiles.

On Windows Server, I run the same command on the same project and I get the following error:

> error NU1202: Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson 5.0.5 is
> not compatible with net50 (.NETFramework,Version=v5.0) / win7-x86.
> Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson 5.0.5 supports: net5.0
> (.NETCoreApp,Version=v5.0)

I've tried creating a new ASP empty app and just installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson. The error I get is the same.

This is my .csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="5.0.5" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

I expected the dotnet CLI to generate the same results on different machines if the tool version is the same, but I guess there's more to it. I've tried cleaning up the NuGet cache, with no luck.

What could be different from one machine to the other that affects the result of the build?

Comment: Try `nuget update -self` in your terminal

Comment: I get 'nuget' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 0):

Try `dotnet --info` to check if you had installed the .NET 5 SDK

Comment: Yes, I do. Actually `dotnet --version` shows 5.0.202 in both machines.

Comment: It's strange... From the supported-os, it should work if installed successfully.
https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/main/release-notes/5.0/5.0-supported-os.md
Maybe try to reinstall .NET SDK, if you got this error from VS, maybe you need to upgrade your VS to the latest

Comment: I've tried reinstalling the SDK, same error. I don't have VS installed on the Windows Server machine, since it's not a development machine, but I'll try installing it just to make sure everything is the same.

Comment: So with VS installed, `dotnet build` still fails, but if I build it from VS it works (which is not what I need, but somehow VS is building it differently).